# Chef - calculate values for a template file

Tags: templates, chef-infra

What`s the best approach (using Chef) to fill a template with values which have to be calculated first? The calculation includes for example: calling a databank for a service id or getting the hardware id from the TPN. There are a few template files which need these values.

My approach is to create a library file (NameConfiguration.rb) generating all required values for the template file (mytest.conf.erb). How can I access these variables within the template file?

[default.rb - cookbook]

```
template '/etc/mytest.conf' do
   source 'mytest.conf.erb'
   mode '0644'
   variables ({ :NAME => '???' })
end
```

[template: mytest.conf.erb]

```
 My test Text <%= @NAME %>
```

[NameConfiguration.rb]

```
 # complex name calculation (just a simple example) 
 class NameGen
    firstName = "Heinz"
    LastName = "Winter"
    def create
      sprintf("%s--%s test", firstName, LastName)
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure the library file `NameConfiguration.rb`  is located within a cookbook’s `/libraries` directory. then you can use the library as [template helper modules](https://docs.chef.io/libraries.html#template-helper-modules)

> A template helper module can be defined in a library. This is useful when extensions need to be reused across recipes or to make it easier to manage code that would otherwise be defined inline on a per-recipe basis.

```rb
template '/path/to/template.erb' do
  helpers(MyHelperModule)
end
```

i strongly suggest you to visit the link above for the documentation and good examples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using "module NameGen" and "def self.create", it`s working as expected, but when I want to use "class NameGen" I get the error message "wrong argument type class (expected module)". Is it also possible to use class instead of module?

Comment: @user5580578: if my answer is good for you, please mark it as accepted solution :) and sure, you can use classes, please refer to the link in the post and see the examples which uses ruby classes and modules

Comment: sorry but it is not working with "class NameGen". The error is "uninitialized constant #<Class:#Chef::Recipe:0x00034562>>::NameGen"

Comment: @user5580578: no need to be sorry. if you followed the chef documentaion, it will work for you. wish you many luck.